# Total weight of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to find the total weight of an `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`.  I have a graph in that form

```
a = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[{...},{...},{...}....etc]
```

How can I find its total weight?

Answer (score 4):

You could just do this:
 if a graph is undirected:

```
Total[UpperTriangularize[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g]], 2]
```

if a graph is directed:

```
Total[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g], 2]
```

or by PropertyValue

```
Total[PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]]
```

Comment: Don't forget the self loops!

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This should deal with undirected, directed and graphs with loops (non-infinite non-zero diagonal elements):

```
totalweight=Total@(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ EdgeList[g])
```

where g is graph of interest